# How to open a whole partition/device for reading/writing on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

In other words, what's the Windows equivalent of `open("/dev/sda")`?

I'm trying to port a Linux app that reads and writes to block devices to Windows, but I know almost nothing about Windows development and I can't find anything on google.

I will also need to enumerate all devices (and possibly their partitions) to present them to the user and unmount them before writing (is that a thing on Windows?).

Comment: As strange as this might seem, the Windows API function for this is named `CreateFile`. What you can open depends on flags and path syntax and possibly Windows security.

Comment: In addition to perusing the documentation (available online at Microsoft MSDN library) and googling things, you might want to take a look at the common disk management in Windows from user point of view, command diskmgmt.msc in e.g. the Run dialog (Windowskey + R).

Comment: Apparently a simple way to find "\\?\" volume device names is command `wmic volume`.

Comment: Or if you want an entire drive they look like `\\?\PhysicalDrive0` and for volumes that have drive letters you can use `\\?\C:`